# SPF: premature end-of-input on private/policy

Tags: debian, postfix, spf

I just moved to a new server with quite the same configuration of the old one, and everything is working fine except SPF. Here are the error message I get:

```
Nov  3 10:49:05 ns3016726 postfix/spawn[16996]: warning: command /usr/bin/python exit status 1
Nov  3 10:49:05 ns3016726 postfix/smtpd[17991]: warning: premature end-of-input on private/policy while reading input attribute name
Nov  3 10:49:06 ns3016726 postfix/spawn[16998]: warning: command /usr/bin/python exit status 1
Nov  3 10:49:06 ns3016726 postfix/smtpd[17991]: warning: premature end-of-input on private/policy while reading input attribute name
Nov  3 10:49:06 ns3016726 postfix/smtpd[17991]: warning: problem talking to server private/policy: Connection reset by peer
```

Here is the master.cf part:

```
policy  unix  -       n       n       -       -       spawn
  user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/policyd-spf /etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf
```

And the main.cf part:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 permit_mynetworks,
 reject_unauth_destination,
 check_policy_service unix:private/policy,
 permit
```

I also try with policy `policyd-spf-perl` which give me almost the same error:

```
Nov  3 11:42:19 ns3016726 postfix/spawn[25476]: warning: command /usr/bin/perl exit status 2
Nov  3 11:42:19 ns3016726 postfix/smtpd[25429]: warning: premature end-of-input on private/policy while reading input attribute name
Nov  3 11:42:20 ns3016726 postfix/spawn[25476]: warning: command /usr/bin/perl exit status 2
Nov  3 11:42:20 ns3016726 postfix/smtpd[25429]: warning: premature end-of-input on private/policy while reading input attribute name
Nov  3 11:42:20 ns3016726 postfix/smtpd[25429]: warning: problem talking to server private/policy: Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried to set `debugLevel` in `/etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf` to 5 but I do not get more details in the `mail.log`...

The main change compared to my previous server is that I now have 2 interfaces (OVH Vrack). ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:b2:a8:28:56
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:b2ff:fea8:2856/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:353965 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:503245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:46523833 (44.3 MiB)  TX bytes:347172834 (331.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:df200000-df220000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:b2:a8:28:57
          inet addr:XXX.80.25.118  Bcast:XXX.80.25.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: XXXX::215:b2ff:fea8:2857/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: XXXX:41d0:c:1076::/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1797021 errors:0 dropped:106 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2341317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:270131307 (257.6 MiB)  TX bytes:2624682043 (2.4 GiB)
          Memory:df100000-df17ffff

eth1:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:b2:a8:28:57
          inet addr:XXX.121.39.211  Bcast:XXX.121.39.211  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df100000-df17ffff

eth1:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:b2:a8:28:57
          inet addr:XXX.254.167.3  Bcast:XXX.254.167.3  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df100000-df17ffff

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:30802000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30802000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:18139282003 (16.8 GiB)  TX bytes:18139282003 (16.8 GiB)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on or on how to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easy, in `master.cf`, I just add to replace:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/policyd-spf /etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf
```

by

```
/usr/bin/policyd-spf /etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf
```

Comment: I don't think that was it, because it didn't work with Perl either.